# Policy card effectiveness timing

Tags: civilization-6

How do policies work with respect to timing in these instances:

A policy card like *newly trained builders get 2 extra build actions:* To get the benefit, does the policy need to be active when construction of a builder is started, completed, both? I suppose when completed/produced makes the most sense, but I have some doubt.

A policy card like *+x production toward y:* Do you need to have the policy in effect before you begin to produce *y?* Suppose you start producing a *y* with no related policy, then apply the policy part-way through, then inactivate the policy. Do you get the production bonus proportional to the time it was active, or does the policy need to be in effect when you start or finish production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Policy cards that apply a yield bonus (including a production bonus to certain items) apply that bonus at the beginning of the turn while active. If you have a city that yields 10 production per turn and it's building a builder, then you activate Ilkum (+30% production to builders), it will contribute 13 per turn. If you replace Ilkum, it will return to 10 per turn. The amount already contributed doesn't change when your policies do.

Other policies take effect if they're active when a specific event occurs. For example, Survey doubles XP gains for recon units if it's active *at the moment they gain XP.* Newly-trained builders count under this category, where the event is the builder being created. If Serfdom is active at the moment that the Builder spawns - typically the beginning of the turn, but it could also be when you purchase one with gold - then it will gain +2 builds. Otherwise, it won't.

Comment: That answer hurts. --Because it's blisteringly clear. :)